# Usage of "it is" in formal, mathematical language

Tags: mathematics, formal-language

I have come across a scientific paper written by non-native speakers where some mathematical formulas are introduced by "it is". For example:

> Proof of Theorem X. Assume xyz. [Long mathematical argument.] Then, it is x>0. QED

Now, I don't think I've ever seen this usage of "it is" elsewhere. Personally, I'd write something like "Then, x>0 holds" or "We have/obtain x>0" or, even more simply, "Then, x>0".

So, I am wondering whether this is idiomatic.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me (native speaker with half a degree in maths)

Comment: Are my reformulations correct? A similar example I found in the same paper is "By Theorem XYZ, it is a*b=c". I guess this doesn't make sense either. I would replace "it is" with "we have", but maybe the latter sounds informal.

Comment: All your reformulations seem good to me; also "we find".

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks. If you post this as an answer, I am going to accept it (unless someone can show in the next 24 hours that using "it is" as above is indeed correct).

Comment: I think it's certainly grammatical. I can also come up with examples of plain English sentences that use something similar, although it may not be very common. But that doesn't address its use in the math domain, which this site can't properly address.

Comment: @JasonBassford What examples of plain English sentences do you have in mind? Maybe that could help. Meanwhile, let's see if someone else has a qualified opinion regarding the scientific domain.

Comment: @Maiaux A possible statement from the board game *Clue*: "Let's assume that the murder weapon is a knife and that the scene of the crime is the kitchen. Then, it is Mr. Plum who is the murderer!"

Comment: @JasonBassford I acknowledge the usage of "it is" in your last sentence. I'm not totally sure/convinced it is of the same kind as in the "mathematical" example in the original post, though. The doubt remains, afaic.

Comment: If this theorem started with the premise that x, y, and z were mutually exclusively greater than 0, and was showing that it was x that was greater than zero, then
"Then, it is x>0" being read aloud as "Then, it is x (that is) greater than 0" comes fairly naturally. On Maiaux's last point, though, this doesn't appear to be the usage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite late to the party, but submitting (an) answer in case it's helpful. I'm speaking as someone who's a native English speaker, has finished a BS in mathematics, and is doing research in CS.

**"Then, it is x>0" is, at best, pretty off-putting.**

In my experience, the grammar involved with mixing mathematical symbols with English sentences is in decent part determined by three things:

1. Utility in conveying meaning
2. Convention
3. Whether the word-substituted outcome is appropriate and grammatical

These factors play off of each other pretty heavily– for #3, for instance, the set of appropriate readings is very much a consequence of the first two points. In this case, the two typical readings of x>0 are:

- "x greater than 0"
- "x is greater than 0"

Neither of these readings works particularly well in "it is x>0", failing #3 (for one thing, my first thought when hearing this is "as opposed to what?"). However, there are situations where utility and convention win out- we've established it's not conventional, though, and from a utility perspective, there are numerous no-greater-effort replacements that are more common, including:

- Then, x>0
- Then, we have (that) x>0
- Then, x>0 follows/holds (although I might instead say "Then, it follows/holds that x>0")
- Then, x>0 is true/is the case (although I might instead say "Then, it is true/is the case that x>0")

Of course, it's true that, at the end of the day, the *important* part of a proof is that your reader understands it and there are no gaps in logic. Nevertheless, I would do a double-take on reading the end of that proof.